# OpenGL Shader error 1282

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am trying to add lighting to my current scene of a simple cube. After setting up my uniforms I get a 1282 error from glGetError() for this piece of code

```
GLuint ambientHandle = glGetUniformLocation(program->getHandle(), "ambientProduct");
glUniform4fv( ambientHandle, 1, ambientProduct );
GLuint diffuseHandle = glGetUniformLocation(program->getHandle(), "diffuseProduct");
glUniform4fv( diffuseHandle, 1, diffuseProduct );
GLuint specularHandle = glGetUniformLocation(program->getHandle(), "specularProduct");
glUniform4fv( specularHandle, 1, specularProduct );
GLuint lightPosHandle = glGetUniformLocation(program->getHandle(), "lightPosition");
glUniform4fv( lightPosHandle, 1, light.position );
GLuint shinyHandle = glGetUniformLocation(program->getHandle(), "shininess");
glUniform1f( shinyHandle, materialShininess );
```

Here are my shaders:
vertex.glsl

```
#version 120

attribute vec4 coord3d;
attribute vec3 normal3d;

// output values that will be interpretated per-fragment
varying  vec3 fN;
varying  vec3 fE;
varying  vec3 fL;

uniform vec4 lightPosition;
uniform mat4 mTransform;

void main()
{
    fN = normal3d;
    fE = coord3d.xyz;
    fL = lightPosition.xyz;

    if( lightPosition.w != 0.0 ) {
    fL = lightPosition.xyz - coord3d.xyz;
    }

    gl_Position = mTransform*coord3d;
}
```

fragment.glsl

```
// per-fragment interpolated values from the vertex shader
varying  vec3 fN;
varying  vec3 fL;
varying  vec3 fE;

uniform vec4 ambientProduct, diffuseProduct, specularProduct;
uniform mat4 mTransform;
uniform vec4 lightPosition;
uniform float shininess;

void main() 
{ 
    // Normalize the input lighting vectors
    vec3 N = normalize(fN);
    vec3 E = normalize(fE);
    vec3 L = normalize(fL);

    vec3 H = normalize( L + E );

    vec4 ambient = ambientProduct;

    float Kd = max(dot(L, N), 0.0);
    vec4 diffuse = Kd*diffuseProduct;

    float Ks = pow(max(dot(N, H), 0.0), shininess);
    vec4 specular = Ks*specularProduct;

    // discard the specular highlight if the light's behind the vertex
    if( dot(L, N) < 0.0 ) {
    specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }

    gl_FragColor = ambient + diffuse + specular;
    gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

The products and position are each a struct of three GLfloats and shininess is a float. I have checked all of the values of the handles and the values I am passing and they all seem valid. Ideas?

--EDIT:
I have narrowed it to the glUniform4fv calls. It happens after each one. Also I have double checked that the program->getHandle() is pointing to something that looks valid.

I have checked program->getHandle is a valid program
Here are the values of all handles:
Program handle 3
ambientHandle 0
diffuseHandle 1
specularHandle 5
lightPosHandle 2
shinyHandle 4

So they all look good. For testing I am commenting out the lines below the ones for ambientProduct. For clarity I am explicitly using this line instead

```
glUniform4f( ambientHandle, ambientProd.x, ambientProd.y, ambientProd.z, ambientProd.w );
```

These are the values for ambientProd at the time that line is executed. 
x = 0.200000003, y = 0.0, z = 0.200000003, w = 1.0

A collaborator on this project moved the call for glUseProgram. Thanks for the help folks.

Answer (score 24):

Error number ´1282` is not very descriptive.

Possible error codes for `glGetUniformLocation` are:

```
GL_INVALID_VALUE
GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

Which don't have a fixed value. Try to get the error string with `gluErrorString()` or take a look in the header to which of those `1282` maps.

Just a shot in the dark: but did you ...

- check your shader got compiled without error?
- check your shader got linked without error?

BTW: return type is GLint not GLuint

"Shaders compiled and linked without error" Hmm, this looks odd.

According to spec (see: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetUniformLocation.xml) `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` should only be generated if:

- program is not a program objec
- program has not been successfully linked

Other question:

- are you sure the `getHandle()`method of the class your `program` Object belongs to returns the right id. I mean the one that was used in the sucessfully linking.

  you should be able to verify with checking if `glIsProgram(program-getHandle())` returns `GL_TRUE`

**EDIT:** Ah - I missed those calls to `glUniform4fv` in your example.

Correct return type for `glGetUniformLocation` is still `GLint`, but I don't think thats the problem.

According to spec (see: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml) `GLUniformXX` generates `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` for a whole bunch of reasons. To me the only one that possibly seems to apply is:

- there is no current program object

  Did you call `glUseProgram (program->getHandle())` prior to trying to calling `glUniform()`?

Comment: Shaders compiled and linked without error and it is the GL_INVALID_OPERATION error

Comment: I missed the call to `glUniform()` in your example - there's a wohle bunch of reasons listed in the spec. IMHO the program not being the active one seeming the only one that possibly applies.

Comment: Wow, I really forgot to call glUseProgram. Tnx.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where I was going from GL3.3 to GLES and had the issue that for `glTexImage2D` calls, the output format must be the same as the internal format.

So I had to change:

`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);`

to

`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);`.

I remember reading it somewhere but completely forgot, so I will just leave this here just in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this error number occurs when you are using a different programID from the programID generated by openGL at the time of creating the shader. It means that you are using a different programID at the time of binding `vertexShader` or `fragmentShader` or whatever other shader you are using.

Comment: I have made a few minor changes to your answer. Please check that my changes are correct and that I have not added any mistakes. You can [edit] the answer further if necessary.