# Inexplicable error while setting a simple uniform in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++, glsl, shader

I am trying to implement god rays, and for that I was rendering my planet and the sun to a downsampled texture with the sun as white and the planet as black so that when the planet occludes the sun, only the part that is visible would get blurred in the next pass.

Here's the high level version of the code in my render loop:

```
curr_program = sun_program;
glUseProgram(curr_program);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glViewport(0, 0, VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);

cam->setupCamera(curr_program);

float white[3] = { 1.f, 1.f, 1.f };
float black[3] = { 1.f, 0.f, 0.f };

GLuint isSunLocation = glGetUniformLocation(curr_program, "isSun");
int value = 1;
cout << "1: " << glGetError() << endl; // output: 0
glUniform1i(isSunLocation, value);
cout << "2: " << glGetError() << endl; // output: 0
ss->render(curr_program, textureManager);
value = 0;
cout << "3: " << glGetError() << endl; // output: 0
glUniform1i(isSunLocation, value);
cout << "4: " << glGetError() << endl; // output 1282
s->render(curr_program, textureManager);
```

Here's my vertex shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 vPosition;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

void main()
{
    mat4 modelView = view * model;
    gl_Position = projection * modelView * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
}
```

And here's my fragment shader:

```
#version 400 core

uniform int isSun;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(isSun, isSun, isSun, 1.0);
}
```

Here's some screenshots of what I'm getting:

[image]
[image]

As explained in the render code, when I try to set the value of isSun second time, I get the error code 1282 after doing the glUniform1i call. As a result, both spheres get colored as white. What I want is for the smaller sphere (sun) to be white, but the bigger one (planet) to be black. From what I understand, it's an invalid value error which means that the shader thinks the value being passed on is not an integer. But clearly, I declare my value specifically as an integer just to be sure.

I also tried setting the isSun value the color value with:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(isSun, isSun, isSun, 1.0);
```

But all I get is white color, which means the value of isSun is not getting updated.

Could anyone explain what might be the issue here? Why is isSun not getting updated?

A simplest of the task like this is driving me crazy!

Comment: There is no 'out' variable in fragment shader, to pass the color to the next step in pipeline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you already seen [Opengl shader error 1282](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722803/opengl-shader-error-1282)?

According to this link, error 1282 can come from many things. As @mikyra suggested:

- try to call `gluErrorString()` to get a more verbose error
- make sure that your shader's program is still in use (we don't know what you are doing in `ss->render(curr_program, textureManager)` maybe a call to `glUseProgram(0)`)

Comment: Well I'll be damned! In my render function, the last line is glUseProgram(0). I just feel plain stupid now. Thanks for pointing that out! This solved my problem! Thanks a lot again.