# Opengl compute shader works at home but nowhere else

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, compute-shader

When running my program at home in visual studio on a computer with i7 and gtx 980ti it works and i can see my scene but when i run the program in school  on a computer with xeon and gtx 1080ti i just get a black screen.

Running Nsight on my home computer shows no api errors while in school there is a 1282 error after the dispatch call.

C++ file

```
lightingShaderProgram.activateShaderProgram();

uniformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, "invView_matrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(invView_matrix));

uniformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, "view_matrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view_matrix));


//CAM pos
uniformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, "view_position");
glUniform3fv(uniformLoc, 1, glm::value_ptr(gameScene->mainCamera->transform.position));


glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, "gPosition"), 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gPosition);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, "gNormal"), 1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gNormal);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, "gAlbedo"), 2);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gAlbedo);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, "gAORoughMet"), 3);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gAORoughMet);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, "gEmissive"), 4);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gEmissive);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, "gSSAO"), 5);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ssaoShaderProgram.ssaoColorBuffer);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(postEffectShaderProgram.gShaderProgram, "FragColor"), 6);
glBindImageTexture(6, lColor, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(postEffectShaderProgram.gShaderProgram, "FragHDRColor"), 7);
glBindImageTexture(7, lHDRColor, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);
int index = 8;

//Lights
for (int i = 0; i < lightsToRender.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << "lights" << lightsToRender.size() << std::endl;
    std::string lightUniform;

    //Type
    lightUniform = "lights[" + std::to_string(i) + "].lightType";
    GLuint loc = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, lightUniform.c_str());
    glUniform1i(loc, GLint(lightsToRender.at(i)->lightComponent->lightType));

    //Position
    lightUniform = "lights[" + std::to_string(i) + "].Position";
    loc = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, lightUniform.c_str());
    glUniform3fv(loc, 1, glm::value_ptr(lightsToRender.at(i)->transform.position));

    //Direction
    lightUniform = "lights[" + std::to_string(i) + "].DirectionVector";
    loc = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, lightUniform.c_str());
    glUniform3fv(loc, 1, glm::value_ptr(lightsToRender.at(i)->transform.up));

    //Color
    lightUniform = "lights[" + std::to_string(i) + "].Color";
    loc = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, lightUniform.c_str());
    glUniform3fv(loc, 1, glm::value_ptr(lightsToRender.at(i)->lightComponent->color));
    //std::cout << " Color" << std::endl << directionalLightsToRender.at(i)->lightComponent->color.x << directionalLightsToRender.at(i)->lightComponent->color.y << directionalLightsToRender.at(i)->lightComponent->color.z << std::endl;

    //Intensity
    lightUniform = "lights[" + std::to_string(i) + "].Intensity";
    loc = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, lightUniform.c_str());
    glUniform1f(loc, lightsToRender.at(i)->lightComponent->intensity);

    //Range
    lightUniform = "lights[" + std::to_string(i) + "].Range";
    loc = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, lightUniform.c_str());
    glUniform1f(loc, lightsToRender.at(i)->lightComponent->range);


    //Light space matrix
    lightUniform = "lights[" + std::to_string(i) + "].lightSpace_matrix";
    loc = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, lightUniform.c_str());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(lightsToRender.at(i)->lightComponent->lightSpaceMatrix));

    //Shadow depthmap
    lightUniform = "lights[" + std::to_string(i) + "].shadowMap";
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram.screenQuadShader, lightUniform.c_str()), index);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+index);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, lightsToRender.at(i)->lightComponent->depthMap);

    index++;

}
glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);
GLint error = glGetError();
glDispatchCompute(display_w / 32, (display_h / 30), 1);
error = glGetError();
glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);
```

C++ buffer creation

```
    void RenderManager::createGBuffer()
{
    //framebufferobject
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &gbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, gbo);

    //g-buffer position
    glGenTextures(1, &gPosition);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gPosition);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, display_w, display_h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    //attach texture to current framebuffer
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gPosition, 0);

    //g-buffer normal
    glGenTextures(1, &gNormal);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gNormal);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, display_w, display_h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    //attach texture to current framebuffer
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gNormal, 0);

    //g-buffer albedo
    glGenTextures(1, &gAlbedo);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gAlbedo);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, display_w, display_h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    //attach texture to current framebuffer
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gAlbedo, 0);

    //g-buffer specular + metallic + AO
    glGenTextures(1, &gAORoughMet);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gAORoughMet);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, display_w, display_h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    //attach texture to current framebuffer
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gAORoughMet, 0);

    //Emmisive
    glGenTextures(1, &gEmissive);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gEmissive);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, display_w, display_h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    //attach texture to current framebuffer
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT4, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gEmissive, 0);


    glDrawBuffers(5, gAttachments);


    //renderbufferobject
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &gRbo);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, gRbo);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, display_w, display_h);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

    //attach renderbufferobject to framebuffer
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, gRbo);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR::GBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete! " << glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) << std::endl;
        if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT)
        {
            std::cout << "Attachment" << std::endl;

        }

    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "SUCCESS::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is complete!" << std::endl;
    }
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

}

void RenderManager::createLPBuffer()
{
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &LPfbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, LPfbo);

    //Color attachments
    glGenTextures(1, &lColor);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, lColor);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, display_w, display_h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, lColor, 0);

    glGenTextures(1, &lHDRColor);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, lHDRColor);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, display_w, display_h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, lHDRColor, 0);

    glGenTextures(1, &lProcessedColor);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, lProcessedColor);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, display_w, display_h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_TEXTURE_2D, lProcessedColor, 0);

    glDrawBuffers(3, pAttachments);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

}
```

GLSL

```
#version 440
#define EPSILON 0.0001
const float PI = 3.14159265359;

layout(local_size_x = 32, local_size_y = 30) in; //gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy(z?) gl_LocalInvocationID.xy(z?)

layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D gPosition;
layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D gNormal;
layout(binding = 2) uniform sampler2D gAlbedo;
layout(binding = 3) uniform sampler2D gAORoughMet;
layout(binding = 4) uniform sampler2D gEmissive;
layout(binding = 5) uniform sampler2D gSSAO;

layout ( binding = 6, rgba32f) uniform image2D FragColor;
layout ( binding = 7, rgba32f) uniform image2D FragHDRColor;

uniform vec3 view_position;
uniform mat4 invView_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;

const int NR_LIGHTS = 32;
struct Light {
    int lightType;
    vec3 Position;
    vec3 DirectionVector;
    vec3 Color;
    float Intensity;
    float Range;
    mat4 lightSpace_matrix;
    sampler2D shadowMap;

};
uniform Light lights[NR_LIGHTS];




float distributionGGX(vec3 normalV, vec3 halfwayV, float roughness){

    //Based on observations by Disney and adopted by Epic Games the 
    //lighting looks more correct squaring the roughness in both 
    //the geometry and normal distribution function.
    float roughness2 = roughness*roughness*roughness*roughness;
    float normalVdotHalfwayV=max(dot(normalV, halfwayV), 0.0);
    float normalVdotHalfwayV2=normalVdotHalfwayV*normalVdotHalfwayV;

    float denominator = normalVdotHalfwayV2*(roughness2-1.0)+1.0;
    denominator= PI *denominator*denominator;

    return roughness2/denominator;
}

float geometrySchlickGGX(float normalVdotViewDirV, float roughness){

    float rough = roughness+1.0;
    float k = (rough*rough)/8.0;
    float denominator = normalVdotViewDirV*(1.0-k)+k;

    return normalVdotViewDirV/denominator;
}

float GeometrySmith(vec3 normalV, vec3 viewDirV, vec3 lightDirV, float k){

    float normalVdotViewDirV = max(dot(normalV, viewDirV), 0.0);
    float normalVdotLightDirV = max(dot(normalV, lightDirV), 0.0);
    float ggx1 = geometrySchlickGGX(normalVdotViewDirV, k);
    float ggx2 = geometrySchlickGGX(normalVdotLightDirV, k);

    return ggx1*ggx2;
}

vec3 fresnelSchlik(float cosTheta, vec3 fresnel0){
    return fresnel0+(1.0-fresnel0)*pow(1.0 -cosTheta, 5.0);
}

void main(){
    // retrieve data from G-buffer
    vec2 uvCoord = vec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy)/vec2(1280,720);// screen = 1280x720
    vec3 FragPos = texture(gPosition, uvCoord).rgb;
    vec3 Normal = texture(gNormal, uvCoord).rgb;
    vec3 Albedo = texture(gAlbedo, uvCoord).rgb;
    vec3 AORoughMet = texture(gAORoughMet, uvCoord).rgb;
    vec3 Emissive = texture(gEmissive, uvCoord).rgb;
    float SSAO = texture(gSSAO, uvCoord).r;
    vec3 viewDir = normalize((view_matrix*vec4(view_position, 1)).xyz - FragPos);

    //Base reflectivity
    vec3 fresnel0 = vec3(0.04);
    fresnel0 = mix(fresnel0, Albedo, AORoughMet.b);

    vec3 totalSpectralRadiance = vec3(0.0);


    //Lights
    for (int i = 0; i < NR_LIGHTS; ++i)
    {
        vec3 lightDir;
        vec3 halfwayDir;
        vec3 radiance;
        float shadow=0;
        if(lights[i].lightType==0){

        }

        //Directional
        if(lights[i].lightType==1){
            lightDir = normalize(lights[i].DirectionVector);
            lightDir = (view_matrix*vec4(lightDir, 0)).xyz;

            halfwayDir = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);

            //Shadow Calculations
            vec4 fragPosLightSpace = lights[i].lightSpace_matrix*invView_matrix*vec4(FragPos, 1.0);
            vec3 projectedCoordninates = fragPosLightSpace.xyz / fragPosLightSpace.w;
            projectedCoordninates = projectedCoordninates*0.5 + 0.5;
            float currentDepth = projectedCoordninates.z;
            vec2 texelSize = 1.0 / textureSize(lights[0].shadowMap, 0);
            if (currentDepth < 1.0) {
                float bias = max(0.05 * (dot(Normal, lightDir)), 0.05);

                for (int x = -1; x <= 1; ++x)
                {
                    for (int y = -1; y <= 1; ++y)
                    {
                        float pcfDepth = texture(lights[0].shadowMap, projectedCoordninates.xy + vec2(x, y) * texelSize).r;
                        shadow += currentDepth-bias > pcfDepth ? 1.0 : 0.0;
                    }
                }
            }
            shadow = shadow / 9.0;
            //End Shadow Calculations

            radiance = lights[i].Color*lights[i].Intensity;
        }

        //Point
        if(lights[i].lightType==2){
            lightDir = normalize((view_matrix*vec4( lights[i].Position, 1)).xyz  - FragPos);
            halfwayDir = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);  
            //
            //Shadow
            //
            float distance = length((view_matrix*vec4( lights[i].Position, 1)).xyz - FragPos);
            float attenuation = 1.0 / (distance*distance); 
            radiance = lights[i].Color*lights[i].Intensity*attenuation;

        }




        //Fresnel
        vec3 fresnel = fresnelSchlik(clamp(dot(halfwayDir, viewDir), 0.0, 1.0), fresnel0);

        //Normal distribution function: approximates the amount the surface's microfacets are aligned to the halfway vector influenced by the roughness of the surface
        float normalDistribution = distributionGGX(Normal, halfwayDir, AORoughMet.g);

        //Geometry function: describes the self-shadowing property of the microfacets.
        float geometryValue = GeometrySmith(Normal, viewDir, lightDir, AORoughMet.g);

        //Cook-Torrance bidirectional reflectance distribution function 
        vec3 nominator = normalDistribution*geometryValue*fresnel;
        float denominator = 4.0 * max(dot(Normal, viewDir), 0.0)*max(dot(Normal, lightDir), 0.0);
        vec3 specular = nominator / max(denominator, 0.001);

        vec3 contributionSpec = fresnel;
        vec3 contributionDif = vec3(1.0) - contributionSpec;
        contributionDif *= 1.0 - AORoughMet.b;

        float normalVdotLightDirV = max(dot(Normal, lightDir), 0.0);
        totalSpectralRadiance += (contributionDif*Albedo / PI + specular)*radiance*normalVdotLightDirV*(1-shadow);
    }
    float ao = AORoughMet.r;
    if (ao < SSAO) {
        ao = SSAO;
    }


    vec3 ambient = vec3(0.03)*Albedo;
    vec3 color= ambient + totalSpectralRadiance*ao;

    //HDR Output
    vec3 HDRValue = vec3(0, 0, 0);
    float brightness = dot(color.rgb, vec3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722));
    if (brightness > 1.0) {
        HDRValue += color;
    }
    HDRValue += Emissive;
    //FragHDRColor = vec4(HDRValue, 1.0);
    imageStore(FragHDRColor, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), vec4(HDRValue.xyz,1.0));

    vec3 outputColor = vec3(0, 0, 0);
    brightness = dot(color.rgb, vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0));
    if (brightness > EPSILON) {
        outputColor += color;
    }
    //FragColor = vec4(outputColor.xyz, 1.0);
    imageStore(FragColor, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), vec4(outputColor.xyz,1.0));

    //FragColor = vec4(ao,ao,ao, 1.0);

}
```

//Edit - Shader Creation

```
GLuint ShaderProgram::CreateShaderData(std::string vertexShader, std::string tesselationControlShader, std::string tesselationEvaluationShader, std::string geometryShader, std::string fragmentShader, std::string computeShader)
{

    // local buffer to store error strings when compiling.
    char buff[1024];
    memset(buff, 0, 1024);
    GLint compileResult = 0;
    ifstream shaderFile;
    std::string shaderText;
    const char* shaderTextPtr;
    GLuint gShaderProgram = 0;

    GLuint vs = 0;
    if (vertexShader != "") {
        //create vertex shader
        vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        shaderFile.open(vertexShader);
        shaderText.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(shaderFile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        shaderFile.close();

        shaderTextPtr = shaderText.c_str();

        // ask GL to use this string as shader code source
        glShaderSource(vs, 1, &shaderTextPtr, nullptr);

        // try to compile this shader source.
        glCompileShader(vs);

        // check for compilation error
        glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileResult);
        if (compileResult == GL_FALSE) {
            // query information about the compilation (nothing if compilation went fine!)
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vs, 1024, nullptr, buff);
            // print to Visual Studio debug console output
            OutputDebugStringA(buff);
        }
    }

    GLuint tcs = 0;
    if (tesselationControlShader != "") {
        //tesselation control shader
        tcs = glCreateShader(GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER);
        shaderFile.open(tesselationControlShader);
        shaderText.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(shaderFile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        shaderFile.close();
        shaderTextPtr = shaderText.c_str();
        glShaderSource(tcs, 1, &shaderTextPtr, nullptr);
        glCompileShader(tcs);
        // query information about the compilation (nothing if compilation went fine!)
        compileResult = GL_FALSE;
        glGetShaderiv(tcs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileResult);
        if (compileResult == GL_FALSE) {
            // query information about the compilation (nothing if compilation went fine!)
            memset(buff, 0, 1024);
            glGetShaderInfoLog(tcs, 1024, nullptr, buff);
            // print to Visual Studio debug console output
            OutputDebugStringA(buff);
        }
    }

    GLuint tes = 0;
    if (tesselationEvaluationShader != "") {
        //tesselation evaluation shader
        tes = glCreateShader(GL_TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER);
        shaderFile.open(tesselationEvaluationShader);
        shaderText.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(shaderFile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        shaderFile.close();
        shaderTextPtr = shaderText.c_str();
        glShaderSource(tes, 1, &shaderTextPtr, nullptr);
        glCompileShader(tes);
        // query information about the compilation (nothing if compilation went fine!)
        compileResult = GL_FALSE;
        glGetShaderiv(tes, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileResult);
        if (compileResult == GL_FALSE) {
            // query information about the compilation (nothing if compilation went fine!)
            memset(buff, 0, 1024);
            glGetShaderInfoLog(tes, 1024, nullptr, buff);
            // print to Visual Studio debug console output
            OutputDebugStringA(buff);
        }
    }

    GLuint gs = 0;
    if (geometryShader != "") {
        //geometry shader
        gs = glCreateShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER);
        shaderFile.open(geometryShader);
        shaderText.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(shaderFile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        shaderFile.close();
        shaderTextPtr = shaderText.c_str();
        glShaderSource(gs, 1, &shaderTextPtr, nullptr);
        glCompileShader(gs);
        // query information about the compilation (nothing if compilation went fine!)
        compileResult = GL_FALSE;
        glGetShaderiv(gs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileResult);
        if (compileResult == GL_FALSE) {
            // query information about the compilation (nothing if compilation went fine!)
            memset(buff, 0, 1024);
            glGetShaderInfoLog(gs, 1024, nullptr, buff);
            // print to Visual Studio debug console output
            OutputDebugStringA(buff);
        }
    }

    GLuint fs = 0;
    if (fragmentShader != "") {
        // fragment Shader
        fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        shaderFile.open(fragmentShader);
        shaderText.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(shaderFile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        shaderFile.close();
        shaderTextPtr = shaderText.c_str();
        glShaderSource(fs, 1, &shaderTextPtr, nullptr);
        glCompileShader(fs);
        // query information about the compilation (nothing if compilation went fine!)
        compileResult = GL_FALSE;
        glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileResult);
        if (compileResult == GL_FALSE) {
            // query information about the compilation (nothing if compilation went fine!)
            memset(buff, 0, 1024);
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fs, 1024, nullptr, buff);
            // print to Visual Studio debug console output
            OutputDebugStringA(buff);
        }
    }

    GLuint cs = 0;
    if (computeShader != "") {
        //compute shader
        cs = glCreateShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER);
        shaderFile.open(computeShader);
        shaderText.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(shaderFile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        shaderFile.close();
        shaderTextPtr = shaderText.c_str();
        glShaderSource(cs, 1, &shaderTextPtr, nullptr);
        glCompileShader(cs);
        // query information about the compilation (nothing if compilation went fine!)
        compileResult = GL_FALSE;
        glGetShaderiv(cs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileResult);
        if (compileResult == GL_FALSE) {
            // query information about the compilation (nothing if compilation went fine!)
            memset(buff, 0, 1024);
            glGetShaderInfoLog(cs, 1024, nullptr, buff);
            // print to Visual Studio debug console output
            OutputDebugStringA(buff);
        }
    }

    //link shader program (connect vs and ps)
    gShaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    if (fragmentShader != "") {
        glAttachShader(gShaderProgram, fs);
    }
    if (tesselationControlShader != "") {
        glAttachShader(gShaderProgram, tcs);
    }
    if (tesselationEvaluationShader != "") {
        glAttachShader(gShaderProgram, tes);
    }
    if (geometryShader != "") {
        glAttachShader(gShaderProgram, gs);
    }
    if (vertexShader != "") {
        glAttachShader(gShaderProgram, vs);
    }
    if (computeShader != "") {
        glAttachShader(gShaderProgram, cs);
    }
    glLinkProgram(gShaderProgram);

    // check once more, if the Vertex Shader and the Fragment Shader can be used
    // together
    compileResult = GL_FALSE;
    glGetProgramiv(gShaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &compileResult);
    if (compileResult == GL_FALSE) {
        // query information about the compilation (nothing if compilation went fine!)
        memset(buff, 0, 1024);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(gShaderProgram, 1024, nullptr, buff);
        // print to Visual Studio debug console output
        OutputDebugStringA(buff);
    }

    //detach shaders
    if (fragmentShader != "") {
        glDetachShader(gShaderProgram, fs);
    }
    if (tesselationControlShader != "") {
        glDetachShader(gShaderProgram, tcs);
    }
    if (tesselationEvaluationShader != "") {
        glDetachShader(gShaderProgram, tes);
    }
    if (geometryShader != "") {
        glDetachShader(gShaderProgram, gs);
    }
    if (vertexShader != "") {
        glDetachShader(gShaderProgram, vs);
    }
    if (computeShader != "") {
        glDetachShader(gShaderProgram, cs);
    }

    //delete shaders
    if (fragmentShader != "") {
        glDeleteShader(fs);
    }
    if (tesselationControlShader != "") {
        glDeleteShader(tcs);
    }
    if (tesselationEvaluationShader != "") {
        glDeleteShader(tes);
    }
    if (geometryShader != "") {
        glDeleteShader(gs);
    }
    if (vertexShader != "") {
        glDeleteShader(vs);
    }
    if (computeShader != "") {
        glDeleteShader(cs);
    }



    return gShaderProgram;
}
```

I think it's a problem with sampler2d and/or image2d because i've had problem with them before in another compute shader.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you look at this question?  They seem to have the same error code.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/15722803/691711

Comment: I don't get any errors on my home computer and the program runs fine, but i get errors on the computers in school. I get the error at the dispatch call so it's something wrong inside the shader that's ok at home but not in school. All shaders compile without error.

Comment: I call glUseProgram() in activateShaderProgram()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deffered rendering with opengl compute shader only works at home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158485/deffered-rendering-with-opengl-compute-shader-only-works-at-home)

Comment: @genpfault: Should have been edited and not reasked, but at least it now contains the missing code.

Comment: Yeah it's but with all my code added, i deleted that one because people just downvote insted of helping.

Comment: What does lightingShaderProgram.activateShaderProgram() do, precisely?  1282 is generated if there is no active program for the compute shader stage.  I've often found some drivers are more forgiving of api mistakes than others...

Comment: void LightingPassShaderProgram::activateShaderProgram()
{
 glUseProgram(screenQuadShader);
}

Comment: @Hamaro: Your last question was off-topic because it didn't contain the relevant code parts, thats why people downvoted. Just note that deleted questions also count for question bans. It is usually preferable if you fix your questions instead of reasking them.

Comment: @Hamaro  screenQuadShader is compiled as GL_COMPUTE_SHADER?

Comment: @Robinson yes it's. I only get api error at dispatch, none at shader creation.

Comment: Failed shader linking/compiling doesn't produce an api error. Do you check `GL_COMPILE_STATE` and `GL_LINK_STATE`. (But I doubt this is the problem because of the uniform setting code which would produce errors when the uniforms aren't available).

Comment: @BDL I just added how i create my shader programs, i believe i check for all possible compilation errors?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. In nvidia nsight->capture frame->misc->compute shader limitations i found that compute shaders just support 32 uniform textures. I had 6 sampler2d for gbuffer and 32 shadow maps sampler2ds. When i changed it to 6+26 it works.

Comment: 8 + 24? What technique are you using that you used 32 shadow maps?